# Problem with footer and login

Tags: login

I have problem with footer in page login and my account not be in bottom

http://www.budoor66.com/login/

also how to make this text in login show just when customer is not be membership

(Access only for members, to view and buy membership package click here)

and disappear when he login

Help me :/

Comment: Edit your question more clearly for us to understand. When he is logged in, why there would be a login page first?

Comment: I mean when I logged in, the text still there how to disappear

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using "Divi" theme and that uses "Layout Builder". You can not insert Php function in the layout builder. However what you can do is install this plugin to execute php within the posts / pages ( it's quite old plugin, try to see if you can find something similar).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exec-php/

and then put this in your text module

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, Member!';
} else {
    echo 'Access only for members, to view and buy  membership package click here
';
}
?>
```

The above code gives you a hint how to go about what you are trying to do.